# snprintf does not create the correct command

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

When I'm debugging my program with gdb and type print command, it prints this :

```
$4 = "sudo asterisk -rx \"pjsip show aor 101\"\000\000b\006@\000\000\000\000\000p\004@\00 ... and so on
```

Normaly it should just create the plain command as a char? If I am right. This leads to another problem, because popen() can not create a proper stream.

Here is my important code:

Comment: Program incomplete, cannot reproduce. What is `row` defined **as**? For one thing. Also, note that what gdb shows you there is a memory dump. The *string* ends at the zero byte (`\000`).

Comment: A diagnostic print of the `command` (that is, `printf("[%s]\n", command);`) would have told you what was being passed to `popen()`.  Similarly, if you'd printed the returned buffer (`printf("[%s]\n", buff);`), it would tell you whether `someth` was present in the data.  You didn't check the return status from `fgets()` — you don't know if it got any data, so you don't know whether the content of `buff` is possibly relevant.  The square brackets added to the printf formats help you identify trailing spaces or embedded newlines or carriage returns, amongst other things.  I usually use them.

Comment: I cannot see any code.

Answer (score 2):

Since `command` is an array (not a `char *`) when you tell gdb to `print command`, it prints the entire contents, including anything in the buffer after the trailing NUL character.  So when you see:

```
$4 = "sudo asterisk -rx \"pjsip show aor 101\"\000\000b\006@\000\000\000\000\000p\004@\00 
                                              ^^^^ -- NUL character
```

Its showing you what snprintf put into the buffer, as well as whatever random stuff happened to be in memory on the stack when the function was started and stack space was reserved for `command`